# Don't want sorting into last column header

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I don't want sorting into last column header. I put a logic as below but it's not working. If I put a static number then it's working properly

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var column = (jQuery("#item_table").children('thead').children('tr').children('th').length-1);
    jQuery("#item_table").tablesorter( {
        headers: {
                column: {
                    sorter: false
                }
           }
    });
});
```

Comment: ...and what's the question?

Comment: I want it dynamic but through througn  headers: {
                column: {
                    sorter: false
                }
           }

Its not working

Comment: That is as well not a question...

Comment: @yckart As per my understanding, he has implemented tablesorter library and wants to remove sorting feature from one of the columns of the table.

Comment: ok, I have one table with sorting option but it's affecting with all "th" i just don't want a sorting on last table header (on th) so i am trying to remove sorting on last "th" but it's not working dynamically.....

Comment: @user2458582 Can you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), please?

Answer (score 1):

The properties in object literals are not evaluated as variables, they're taken as literal strings. So you need to use array notation to set a variable property.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var column = (jQuery("#item_table").children('thead').children('tr').children('th').length-1);
    headers = {};
    headers[column] = { sorter: false };
    jQuery("#item_table").tablesorter( {
        headers: headers
    });
});
```

Comment: Removed an extraneous brace, try it now

Comment: Added the missing `sorter:` key

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var mcolumn = jQuery("#item_table").find('th').length-1;
    var obj={};
    obj[mcolumn]={ sorter: false};
    jQuery("#item_table").tablesorter( {
        headers: obj
    });
});
```

**Fiddle** http://fiddle.jshell.net/q87c6/

Comment: Why are you calling `parseInt()` on something that's already an integer?